# First moment inequality implies tail distribution inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $U,V$ be two continuous random variables, both with continuous CDF. Suppose that $\mathbb E V \geq \mathbb E U$. Can one conclude that $\mathbb P(V> x) \geq \mathbb P(U>x)$ for all $x\geq 0$? If not, what additional conditions are needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for example $U \sim N(0,2)$, $V \sim N(1,1)$, i.e. both normally distributed but with different means and variances.

Then $\mathbb{E} V = 1 > 0 = \mathbb{E} U$, but since the variance of $U$ is larger than that of $V$, after some point $x_0$ you'll have that $\mathbb{P}(U > x) > \mathbb{P}(V > x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an argument with may make think it's not true: if $Y$ is a positive random variable, then $E(X)=\int_0^{+\infty}P(X>t)dt$. The fact that $P(U>x)\geqslant P(V>x)$ seems much stronger than $E(U)\geqslant E(V)$.